# FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)

Tags: python, sublimetext3, file-not-found

I started using Sublime Text 3 just to see how it works and when I was coding I downloaded SublimeREPL package for python. And when I tried to run my little code this error shows up : `FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)`

Here is the code:

```
a = int(input("num "))        
print("num is ", a)
```

I'm new to Sublime so I don't know what to do now, any kind of help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You were running this in the sublime repl? or in a file? It seems to be suggesting you are trying to run a file that does not exist.

Comment: I tried running this in sublime repl, but everytime I do it it just shows up this error

Comment: @MarkoVuger Did you save the code to a file?